# Set breakpoint in imported python module in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to set a breakpoint in an external Python module in VS code.

I have tried editing the source file and inserting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` where I want the breakpoint.

This enters the pdb command line debugger rather than the debugger in the VS Code GUI.

How do I set a breakpoint in an imported Python module so that I enter the VS Code debugger?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Marvin's suggestion appears to be sufficient:

> add a launch configuration `"justMyCode":false` .
> See [code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode)

Answer (score 6):

Besides adding `"justMyCode":false` as mentioned in other answers, there's another minor detail that took me a while to realize. You have to use the "Run" button at the top left:

[image]

And NOT the "Run Debug Python File" button at the top right:

[image]

Hope that helps saving time of others.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!
(why would the behavior of these 2 buttons be different..)

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the folder containing the source code of the imported module into the project, using file -> add folder to workspace.  In my case this was `/Users/robinl/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/great_expectations/`

Within VS code, you can then navigate to the file you want to debug and set a breakpoint by clicking to the left of the code as normal.

Comment: Also, you may need to add a launch configuration ```"justMyCode":false``` .  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode

Comment: Answer given by @Marvin appears to me to be the only necessary step (just tried and it worked)

Comment: In VS code version 1.51.0 Marvin's answer is enuf, no need to import the folder! @sivano you should post that as an answer here, the current accepted answer is overkill.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me! Setting `"justMyCode": false` was not enough in my case. Thank you so much!