# Why are breakpoints in site-packages code disabled when I start debugger?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

```
MacOS Monterey
Python 3.9.13
VS Code 1.76.2
pytest==7.2.0
```

I'm running out of a virtualenv.  When I debug one of my unit tests and try to step into a library function, it doesn't step in, it just runs to completion.  Explicitly setting breakpoints in the library code has no effect.  I have justMyCode set to false in launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Per [Set breakpoint in imported python module in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373359), I tried adding site-packages to my workspace, but that didn't make any difference.

I can see the breakpoints set in the library code:  [image: breakpoints set]

As soon as I do "Debug test", the breakpoints in the library code get disabled: [image: disabled breakpoints]

Comment: This is called **Unbound Breakpoint**. Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74565249/18359438) solve your problem?

Comment: Interesting.  If I follow the suggestion there, i.e. try to re-add the breakpoint after starting to debug, I get: "Breakpoint in file excluded by filters.

Note: may be excluded because of "justMyCode" option (default == true).Try setting "justMyCode": false in the debug configuration (e.g., launch.json)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MingJie-MSFT got me pointed in sort-of the right direction, but [How to disable "just my code" setting in VSCode debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980448) is really what I needed.  Using either of these in my launch.json gets things working (although I will confess to not fully understanding the details):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "purpose": [
                "debug-test"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        },
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug Unit Test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "test",
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

The first one is what https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests recommends, so I'll go with that.  And having site-packages added to my workspace turned out to be immaterial.

PS, I just saw the comment in [How to disable "just my code" setting in VSCode debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980448): `"request": "test" is deprecated use "purpose" instead.`

Also, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14388 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17644 are related to this.